# Sending query strings with $.ajax type OPTIONS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My REST API developer told me to check if a file is available for download before going to the actual link by first doing an ajax call using `OPTIONS` type.

If it returns OK, then I can go ahead and redirect the browser to that page and download the file.

```
return $.ajax({
  type: 'OPTIONS',
  url: 'http://api/account-data',
  data: {user_id: '5'}
}).done(function(data) {
  // redirect browser to http://api/account-data?user_id=5
});
```

The problem I encountered is that I can't attach any query strings when I use `OPTIONS`. Also, I've never heard of anyone using `OPTIONS` before. From what I've read, the browser does this automatically when doing certain cross-origin calls. I told him this, but I was told to search for a solution to attach the query strings. Is there a way?

Comment: the `data` field is the query string though.... so I think you may be misusing the word query string. Your example should produce the output URL `http://api/account-data?user_id=5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also, I've never heard of anyone using OPTIONS before.

People are generally pretty bad about using HTTP correctly.

That said, I would expect to use a HEAD request to determine is a resource was available or not.

> From what I've read, the browser does this automatically when doing certain cross-origin calls.

The CORS spec mandates an OPTIONS request as a pre-flight request under some circumstances, but OPTIONS predated CORS and there are other reasons to use that HTTP verb.

> I was told to search for a solution to attach the query strings. Is there a way?

jQuery ignores `data` when you make an OPTIONS request. Put the query string directly in the URL.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'OPTIONS',
  url: 'http://api/account-data?user_id=5'
})
```